# How to join DataTables?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable

I have two `DataTable`s. I have some data that was been retrieved from an XML file on the internet into a `DataTable` called `rates`. I also have a `DataTable` with a set of finanical trades that has been retrieved from a database called `openTrades` with code like this:

```
DataTable rates = DB.GetCurrentFxPrices("http://rates.fxcm.com/RatesXML");
DataTable openTrades = DB.GetOpenTrades();
```

I want to add a column to `openTrades` called `rate` and put in there the current rate from the `rates` `DataTable` joining on a column called `symbol`.

the rates `DataTable` has the following columns:

`Bid, Ask, High, Low, Direction, Last, Symbol`

The openTrades `DataTable` has the following relevant columns:

`tradeId, symbol` and the newly added `rate` column. I'm looking for the most efficient way to join this data together and have the results in the `openTrades DataTable` in the new `rate` column.

**EDIT**

I'm trying this code:

```
DBUtil DB = new DBUtil();
DataTable rates = DB.GetCurrentFxPrices("http://rates.fxcm.com/RatesXML");
DataTable openTrades = DB.GetOpenTrades();

openTrades.Columns.Add("Bid", typeof(decimal));
openTrades.Columns.Add("Ask", typeof(decimal));

var query = from DataRow tradeRow in openTrades.Rows
            join DataRow rateRow in rates.Rows
            on tradeRow.Field<string>("symbol") equals rateRow.Field<string>("Symbol")
            select new
            {
                TradeRow = tradeRow,
                //Bid = rateRow.Field<decimal>("Bid"),
                //Ask = rateRow.Field<decimal>("Ask")
                Rate = (rateRow.Field<decimal>("Bid") + rateRow.Field<decimal>("Ask"))/2
            };

foreach (var item in query)
{
    //item.TradeRow["Bid"] = item.Bid;
    //item.TradeRow["Ask"] = item.Ask;
    item.TradeRow["lastPrice"] = item.Rate;
}
```

But I get this error on  the `select`:

`System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join your existing tables with the following query, and then iterate over the resulting sequence to update your `Rate` values in the trade table.

```
var query = from DataRow tradeRow in openTrades.Rows 
            join DataRow rateRow in rates.Rows 
            on tradeRow.Field<string>("Symbol") equals rateRow.Field<string>("Symbol")
            select new 
            {
                 TradeRow = tradeRow,
                 Rate = rateRow.Field<decimal>("Rate") // use actual type
            };

foreach (var item in query)
{
     item.TradeRow["Rate"] = item.Rate;
}
```

Your `openTrades` table should reflect the changes, and you can continue to do whatever work you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed your code on line starting `Rate` to `Rate = (rateRow.Field<decimal>("Bid") + rateRow.Field<decimal>("Ask"))/2` because I want the average of the bid and the ask price (there is not rate price). I then changed the line item.TradeRow in your foreach to `item.TradeRow["lastPrice"] = item.Rate;` but I get this error on the `select` line: `System.InvalidCastException {"Specified cast is not valid."}` I've edited my question with the complete code I'm using.

Comment: @Mark, those columns in your rates table might not be decimal fields, they could be doubles or another format. Try `<double>` initially or test the type of the data.

Comment: That was it! This code fixed it: `Rate = (decimal.Parse(rateRow.Field<string>("Bid")) + decimal.Parse(rateRow.Field<string>("Ask")))/2`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using Linq to do this?

Something similar to the following should do what you need.  The resulting anonymous type could be loaded into a DataTable if needed or just bound directly with a grid control.

```
using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient()) {
var openTrades = new [] {
    new {tradeId="000", symbol="EURUSD"},
    new {tradeId="001", symbol="USDJPY"}
};

var resultData = XElement.Parse(wc.DownloadString("http://rates.fxcm.com/RatesXML"))
    .Elements("Rate")
    .Select(x=>new {
        Symbol=x.Attribute("Symbol").Value, 
        Bid=x.Element("Bid").Value,
        Ask=x.Element("Ask").Value,
        High=x.Element("High").Value,
        Low=x.Element("Low").Value,
        Direction=x.Element("Direction").Value,
        Last=x.Element("Last").Value
    })
    .ToList()
    .Join(openTrades, x=>x.Symbol, x=>x.symbol, (rate,trades)=> new {trades.tradeId, rate.Symbol, rate.Ask, rate.Bid, rate.High, rate.Low, rate.Direction, rate.Last})
    .ToList();
```

}

To make this work, you will need the following namespaces referenced:
System.Linq
System.Xml.Linq

Good luck!